# How to prevent bottom edge of Grid from showing through Border

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to make a simple login form with rounded corners. Below is a screenshot of the form:

[image]

There is a line segment at the bottom; it is transparent.  Please show me how I can change my XAML to get rid of this line.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Login"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Login" WindowStyle="None"  AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="194" d:DesignWidth="358" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Border BorderBrush="#9DE5F5" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="8" Width="343">
    <Grid Background="#9DE5F5" Width="337" ShowGridLines="False" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="108*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="286*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="FontSize"  Value="16" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"  Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"  Value="Right" />
                <Setter Property="Padding"  Value="8" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,10,15,5" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,10,15,5" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" >Username:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >Password:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="txtUserName" Background="White" />
        <PasswordBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="txtPassword" Background="White" PasswordChar="*" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,10,15,10" Width="80" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13" Background="SteelBlue">Login</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,20,5,10" Width="30" Background="Red" Foreground="White" >X</Button>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 4px border on the `Border` is the same color as the `Grid` you should just get rid of it.

If they are the same color, there usually are some visible lines where the transition from the border to the actual background happens like in this case.

I would fix it by setting the `Background` on the `Border` instead of the `Grid`, and completely removing the `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush` properties from the `Border`.

Looks very fine on my computer :-)

```
<Border Background="#9DE5F5" CornerRadius="8" Width="343">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
    ....
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a margin of -1 is a quick hack but gets rid of it.

```
<Grid Background="White" Width="337" ShowGridLines="False"  Margin="-1">
```